# How to delegate event in case of button child is in the parent class under a modal

Tags: javascript, html, delegates

The problem I am dealing with is to delegate an event in case of a click. The html modal snippet is:

```
<div id="addQues" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Input Fields</h4>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="optCount" name="optCount" value="<?php echo $optCounter?>">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input name="quesText" id="quesText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question Text" style="height: 200px" autofocus>
        <select name="quesType" id="quesType" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
            <option value="Single Choice" id="SC" name="SC">Single Choice</option>
            <option value="Multiple Choice" id="MC" name="MC">Multiple Choice</option>
            <option value="Plain Text" id="TXT" name="TXT">Plain Text</option>
            <option value="Image based" id="ÌMG" name="IMG">Image based</option>
            <option value="Video Based" id="VID" name="VID">Video Based</option>
            <option value="Conjoint" id="CNG" name="CNG">Conjoint</option>
        </select>
        <div id="optList" name="optList">
            <div style="display:flex; vertical-align:top;" class="cooldiv">
                <input name="optionNum_<?php echo $optCounter?>" id="optionNum_<?php echo $optCounter?>" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option No." style="width: 100px" autofocus>
                <input name="optionText_<?php echo $optCounter?>" id="optionText_<?php echo $optCounter?>" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Text" autofocus>
                <button type="button" class="deleteMe">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="addNext">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery code is:

```
 $(".deleteMe").on("click",".cooldiv",function(){
   $(this).closest("div").remove();
   var optCount = parseInt($("#optCount").val());
   optCount = optCount-1;
   alert(optCount)
   $("#optCount").val(optCount);
});
$(".addNext").on("click",".cooldiv",function(){
    var optCount = parseInt($("#optCount").val());
    optCount = optCount+1;
    $("#optList").append('<div style="display:flex; vertical-align:top;" class="cooldiv"><input name="optionNum_'+optCount+'" id="optionNum_'+optCount+'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option No." style="width: 100px" autofocus><input name="optionText_'+optCount+'" id="optionText_'+optCount+'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Text" autofocus><button type="button" class="deleteMe">X</button><button type="button" class="addNext">+</button></div>');
    $("#optCount").val(optCount);
    alert(optCount)
});
```

So, basically I want to add or remove options (add/remove class cooldiv) when the + or x buttons are clicked. But it's not happening this way.

UPDATE:

The complete code is this:

```
<?php   require "login/loginheader.php"; 
        $questionCounter = 1;
        $optCounter      = 1;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="login/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addQues">Input Question No. <?php echo $questionCounter ?></button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="addQues" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Input Fields</h4>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" id="optCount" name="optCount" value="<?php echo $optCounter?>">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input name="quesText" id="quesText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question Text" style="height: 200px" autofocus>
            <select name="quesType" id="quesType" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
                <option value="Single Choice" id="SC" name="SC">Single Choice</option>
                <option value="Multiple Choice" id="MC" name="MC">Multiple Choice</option>
                <option value="Plain Text" id="TXT" name="TXT">Plain Text</option>
                <option value="Image based" id="ÌMG" name="IMG">Image based</option>
                <option value="Video Based" id="VID" name="VID">Video Based</option>
                <option value="Conjoint" id="CNG" name="CNG">Conjoint</option>
            </select>
            <div id="optList" name="optList">
                <div style="display:flex; vertical-align:top;" class="cooldiv">
                    <input name="optionNum_<?php echo $optCounter?>" id="optionNum_<?php echo $optCounter?>" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option No." style="width: 100px" autofocus>
                    <input name="optionText_<?php echo $optCounter?>" id="optionText_<?php echo $optCounter?>" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Text" autofocus>
                    <button type="button" class="deleteMe">X</button>
                    <button type="button" class="addNext">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-signin">
        <div class="alert alert-success">You have been <strong>successfully logged in</strong>.</div>
        <a href="login/logout.php" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>

<script>
$(".deleteMe").on("click",'.cooldiv',function(){
   $(this).closest("div").remove();
   var optCount = parseInt($("#optCount").val());
   optCount = optCount-1;
   alert(optCount)
   $("#optCount").val(optCount);
});
$(".addNext").on("click",'.cooldiv',function(){
    var optCount = parseInt($("#optCount").val());
    optCount = optCount+1;
    $("#optList").append('<div style="display:flex; vertical-align:top;" class="cooldiv"><input name="optionNum_'+optCount+'" id="optionNum_'+optCount+'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option No." style="width: 100px" autofocus><input name="optionText_'+optCount+'" id="optionText_'+optCount+'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Text" autofocus><button type="button" class="deleteMe">X</button><button type="button" class="addNext">+</button></div>');
    $("#optCount").val(optCount);
    alert(optCount)
});
</script>
```

When I click on Input Question No. 1/2..., a modal opens up with option # and option text in it. I want when the button + or x is clicked, another option field with option # and option text adds or the same gets removed. Without delegation, it won't happen, but using delegation like this, it's not even working.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? jsfiddle/snippet? something that demonstrates the problem (and not only code block)

Comment: have a look at this here: https://jsfiddle.net/ev6kajjf/

Comment: Did you have a look at the above jsfiddle? :)

Comment: only css part may be missing and the modal thing is not working correctly in the jsfiddle.. rest, pls tell me what's wrong..

Comment: Also jquery is missing, and probably bootstrap... which means it not a **working example**. It's still just code blocks. Make it a **working** example, let us know what is the problem (what you do/where you click/what you expect/what not happen).

Comment: I updated the question itself, sorry for my bad English. I hope it helps better. The bootstrap and jquery-min exist in the as-mentioned directory as standard files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132933/discussion-between-shashish-chandra-and-dekel).

Comment: new working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ev6kajjf/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to even delegation, but to wrong usage of events and dynamic elements.

You should use

```
$("#optList").on("click",'.deleteMe',function(){
```

and

```
$("#optList").on("click",'.addNext',function(){
```

Because the `#optList` element exists all the time, and the new elements that you add dynamically are `.deleteMe` and `.addNext`.

Here is the jsfiddle that should work as you expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/ev6kajjf/7/

(note that you still have problems there with the value of optCount. I'm not sure why it has `i` to start with: `<input type="hidden" id="optCount" name="optCount" value="i">`).

Comment: Even here, When the new options tabs adds on, Clicking on + or x dont work on these new ones.

Comment: I didn't notice you add new `.cooldiv` elements all the time. When working with dynamic elements you should always use the element that **exists all the time** and attach the `click` event to that element. I updated the answer using the `#optList` element.